# Evaluating the sum of $\frac{n^x}{y^n}$ and $\frac{\log_a(n)}{n^b}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there any closed form for the following series or even for particular values of $(a,b,x,y)$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^x}{y^n} \space \space \space or \space \space \space\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log_a(n)}{n^b}$$

($a,b,x,y$ are all $\in Z$)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first series with $x$ taking small positve integer values ... $x=0,1,2$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y^n} = \frac{\frac{1}{y}}{1-\frac{1}{y}}=\frac{1}{y-1} \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{y^n} = \frac{\frac{1}{y}}{(1-\frac{1}{y})^2}=\frac{y}{(y-1)^2} \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^2}{y^n} = \frac{\frac{1}{y}(1+\frac{1}{y})}{(1-\frac{1}{y})^3}=\frac{y(1+y)}{(y-1)^3} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
by repeatedly appling the operator $ -y \frac{d}{dy} $ to these formulea one could calculate for any $x \in \mathbb{N} $.

The second series is related to the derivative of the Riemann zeta function. I will give more detail, if needs be.

Edit: The next three formulea in the sequence are 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{y(1+4y+y^2)}{(y-1)^4} \\
\frac{y(1+11y+11y^2+y^3)}{(y-1)^5} \\
\frac{y(1+26y+66y^2+26y^3+y^4)}{(y-1)^6} \\
\end{eqnarray*}
The coefficients of the polynomials in the numerators are related to the Eulerian numbers. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number

Comment: :o I'd be interested in the specifics of those Eulerian numbers.

Comment: Oh, I see it.  That's pretty nifty. One applies the identity$$n^k=\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}A(k,m)\binom{n+m}k$$And sum it over $n$, using the binomial expansion theorem.  Nifty.

Comment: The Eulerian numbers appear to have deep links to the Stirling numbers ... hence your solution in terms of Bell polynomials. & as your above remark shows they are related to Bernoulli numbers (via Faulhabers formula) ... there is some really cool stuff here ! @SimplyBeautifulArt

Answer (score 0):

For a nicer looking form, note that

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$$

Set $x\mapsto e^x$ to get

$$\frac1{1-e^x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{kx}$$

Differentiate $n$ times.

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac1{1-e^x}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^ne^{kx}$$

Set $e^x=1/y$.

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac1{1-e^x}\bigg]_{e^x=1/y}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^n}{y^k}$$

The $n$th derivative may be calculated using [Faà di Bruno's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula), which yields

$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac1{1-e^x}\bigg]_{e^x=1/y}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k!}{(1-\frac1y)^{k+1}}B_{n,k}\underbrace{\left(\frac1y,\dots,\frac1y\right)}_{n-k+1}$$

where $B_{n,k}$ is a [Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomial).

---

For the second, note that

$$\frac{\log_a(n)}{n^x}=\frac1{\ln(a)}\frac{\ln(n)}{n^x}=-\frac1{\ln(a)}\frac d{dx}\frac1{n^x}$$

Thus, the given sum is

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\log_a(n)}{n^x}=-\frac1{\ln(a)}\frac d{dx}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^x}=-\frac{\zeta'(x)}{\ln(a)}$$